# Ошибка DEP0800 (версия пакета WindowsAppRuntime и ОС несовместимы)

Tags: .net, maui

Запускаю стартовое приложение MAUI на Windows. Режим разработчика включён. Получаю ошибку:

> Ошибка DEP0800: Не удалось установить требуемую платформу
> "C:\Users\Admin.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.2.221209.1\buildTransitive..\tools\MSIX\win10-x64\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.2.msix".
> [0x80073CFD] Windows не удается установить пакет
> Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.2_2000.707.2303.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe,
> так как он не совместим с устройством. Пакет можно установить на
> устройствах семейства Windows.Universal с ОС версии 10.0.17763.0 или
> более поздней. Сейчас на устройстве используется ОС версии
> 10.0.17134.829.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился обновлением операционной системы. Оказывается, моё последнее такое действие датируется 2019-м годом.